# Can't find migration when running drush migration:status

Tags: 8, drush, migrations

I'm trying a tutorial to migrate users data from a CSV file. 
From here: https://u.group/thinking/drupal-8-csv-migration/

I've created a module as suggested. Here is the code:

**/config/install/migrate_plus.migration.demo_user_migration.yml**

```
id: demo_user_migration
langcode: en
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - user_migrate
label: 'User migration from CSV'
source:
  plugin: csv
  track_changes: true
  path: /config/users.csv
  header_row_count: 1
  ids: 
    - Uid
destination:
  plugin: entity:user
process:
  name: Name
  mail: E-mail
  field_last_name: First Name
  field_first_name: Last Name
  status: Active status
migration_dependencies:
  required: {  }
  optional: {  }
```

**user_migrate.info.yml**

```
name: User Migrate
type: module
description: Custom Migrate of Users using a CSV file
core: 8.x
package: Migration
dependencies:
    - migrate_source_csv
    - migrate_plus
    - migrate_tools
```

**user_migrate.module**

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains teacher_migrate.module.
 */

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_help().
 */
function user_migrate_help($route_name, RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
  switch ($route_name) {
    // Main module help for the custom_user_migrate module.
    case 'help.page.user_migrate':
      $output = '';
      $output .= '<h3>' . t('About') . '</h3>';
      $output .= '<p>' . t('User Migrate') . '</p>';
      return $output;

  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_migration_plugins_alter().
 */
function teacher_migrate_migration_plugins_alter(&$definitions) {
  $definitions['demo_user_migration']['source']['path'] =
    drupal_get_path('module', 'user_migrate') . $definitions['demo_user_migration']['source']['path'];
}
```

I've enabled the module from the *Extend* page.

However, when I run `drush migration:status` the migration I've created is not found. This confirmed by executing `drush migrate:import demo_user_migration`

Do you know where the problem can be?

Comment: Is the path definitely correct in migrate_plus.migration.demo_user_migration.yml?

Comment: Yes, all the paths are correct

Answer (score 0):

Did you try clearing drush cache with **drush cr drush**?

Also, the correct notation for checking the status is **drush migrate-status demo_user_migration**

Comment: Yes, I've tried the first command. The second command returns an empty table.